# Error in my plugin in eclipse while trying to access excel sheet

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a plugin for my Java project in Eclipse. For that I am just using the HEllo World Template. But instead of displaying "Hello, Eclipse World", I want it to display contents of a file.
For that I need the plugin to:

1. open excel file, read a particular cell, and paste that cell content on the file in append mode.
2. open the text file and read and write the contents of the file on the Message dialog box that is opened when plugin runs.

The only issue I am facing here is in the excel part.  The text file read and write is working fine.
I am getting the following errors in my Eclipse Plugin while running it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook cannot be found by SOHELPME_1.0.0.qualifier
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
```

Following are my plugin files:
plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            id="SOHELPME.commands.category"
            name="Sample Category">
      </category>
      <command
            categoryId="SOHELPME.commands.category"
            name="Sample Command"
            id="SOHELPME.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="sohelpme.handlers.SOHandler"
            commandId="SOHELPME.commands.sampleCommand">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="SOHELPME.commands.sampleCommand"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            sequence="M1+6">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="SOHELPME.menus.sampleMenu"
               label="Sample Menu"
               mnemonic="M">
            <command
                  commandId="SOHELPME.commands.sampleCommand"
                  id="SOHELPME.menus.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
               id="SOHELPME.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
                  id="SOHELPME.toolbars.sampleCommand"
                  commandId="SOHELPME.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.png"
                  tooltip="Say hello world">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: SOHELPME
Bundle-SymbolicName: SOHELPME;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: sohelpme.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.17.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
Automatic-Module-Name: SOHELPME
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 poi-4.1.2/poi-4.1.2.jar,
 poi-4.1.2/poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar,
 poi-4.1.2/poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar,
 poi-4.1.2/ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar,
 poi-4.1.2/lib/commons-collections4-4.4.jar
```

I have added the required apache poi jar files required for the excel execution part

build.properties

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/
```

My handler class

```
package sohelpme.handlers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;

public class SOHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        String content = null;
        try
        {
            //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("/Users/rheajose/Desktop/Unimelb/SY project materials/SEDE/SO.xlsx"));
            //Excel part
            FileWriter writer;
            String vOutput;
            //Reading Keywords from test.txt
            File file = new File("/Users/rheajose/eclipse-workspace/Cerorrrs/test.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) 
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    if(line.contains("c cannot be resolved to a variable"))
                    {
                        vOutput=ReadCellData(1, 2);   //starts from 0
                        //System.out.println(vOutput);
                        writer = new FileWriter("/Users/rheajose/eclipse-workspace/Cerorrrs/test.txt", true);
                        writer.write("\n\n**StackOverflow**\n");
                        writer.write(vOutput);
                        writer.close();
                        //str = line;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Displaying the contents of the file
            String filePath = "/Users/rheajose/eclipse-workspace/Cerorrrs/test.txt";
            File file1 = new File(filePath);
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file1.toPath()));
    
            //Display the contents of the text file in a dialog box
            //MessageDialog.openInformation(window.getShell(),"StackOverflow",content);
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "SOHELPME",
                content);
        return null;
    }
    //method defined for reading a cell  
    public static String ReadCellData(int vRow, int vColumn)  
        {  
            String value=null;          //variable for storing the cell value  
            Workbook wb=null;           //initialize Workbook null  
            try  
            {  
                //reading data from a file in the form of bytes  
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("/Users/rheajose/Desktop/Unimelb/SY project materials/SEDE/SO.xlsx");  
                //constructs an XSSFWorkbook object, by buffering the whole stream into the memory  
                wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);  
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)  
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
            catch(IOException e1)  
            {  
                e1.printStackTrace();  
            }
            Sheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);   //getting the XSSFSheet object at given index  
            Row row=sheet.getRow(vRow); //returns the logical row  
            Cell cell=row.getCell(vColumn); //getting the cell representing the given column  
            value=cell.getStringCellValue();    //getting cell value  
            return value;               //returns the cell value  
        } 
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my project explorer view:
[image: Project Explorer view]

I need to know where I am going wrong or if I am missing out on something. I even checked the path for `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory` in my project and it's there. I have no idea why am I still getting this error.

Any ideas?? Ready to add additional comments if you need more information.

This is the output I am getting right now If I don't add the excel part in the handler class. Just reading and writing text file:
[image]
My expectation is that below the **StackOverflow**, data should be pasted which is copied from excel file. But only that part of my code is not running.

Comment: Your build.properties needs to include the poi-4.1.2 directory in the bin.includes otherwise it will not be present in the built plug-in.